# Want the variable value under the script tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pattern-matching

I have extract the scrip tag form my HTML source. But want the variable values from the  tag.
Want the value of the dataForTemplate variable.
the script is as follows:

```
      <script>
        var customizedContactUsUrl =
        var dataForTemplate = {
          redirectToOrg : 'Redirecting you to your organization...',
          actionUrl:document.getElementById('actionUrl').action,
          relayState:'3IUARpZFHyXO6th5WtiE5tJLmrHRpc',
          samlValue:'PHNhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlIHhtbG5zOnNhbWxwPS,
          samlKey:'SAMLResponse',
        }
        var validEmailInputHint = 'Enter a valid email address, formatted as user@company.com.'
        </script>
```

Tried the following code but not working:

```
pattern = re.compile('var dataForTemplate = (.);')
            if(pattern.match(str(required_data.string))):
                data = pattern.match(required_data.string)
                print("data",data)
                stock = json.loads(data.groups()[0])
                print(stock)
```

Comment: `json.loads( "{" + required_data.string.split('{')[1].split('}')[0] + "}" )` ?

Comment: there is `document.getElementById('actionUrl').action,` which is not correct element in JSON data. You would have to skip this element or run JavaScript to get value from this function. And it would need `Selenium`

Comment: text "not working"` is the most useless information. You should describe it. We can't run code to see what is the problem. If you get error message then you should put it in question (not in comment) as text (not image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex will likely fail as the `.` will match a single character except line terminators and then expect a `;`. You want to carry matching until you hit the closing } so you need to lazy match:

```
var dataForTemplate = ([\s\S]+?})
```

Explanation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in my code bellow are too much splits, but hope it will help:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'home.html'
with open(url) as file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser')

script_text = str(soup.find('script'))
my_var = script_text.split('var')[2]
my_var_value = my_var.split(' = ')[1]

print(my_var_value)
# {
#     redirectToOrg : 'Redirecting you to your organization...',
#     actionUrl:document.getElementById('actionUrl').action,
#     relayState:'3IUARpZFHyXO6th5WtiE5tJLmrHRpc',
#     samlValue:'PHNhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlIHhtbG5zOnNhbWxwPS,
#     samlKey:'SAMLResponse',
#   }
```